# JQuery .insertAfter() DOM elements

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML Table which in which i want to manipulate using JQuery

Table:

```
<Table>

<TR>

<TD><div class=ExternalClass00FA6D5A488C4B2582667D6D8DF15F79>Value 1</div></TD>

<TD class="ms-disc-bordered-noleft">Value 2</TD>

<TD class="ms-disc-bordered-noleft">Value 3</TD>

<TD class="ms-disc-bordered-noleft">
<A HREF="/Threaded.aspx?RootFolder=%2fLists&amp;FolderCTID=0x01200">Value 4</A>
</TD></TR>  
...............
<TR>

<TD><div class=ExternalClass00FA6D5A488C4B2582667D6D8DF15F79>Value 1</div></TD>

<TD class="ms-disc-bordered-noleft">Value 2</TD>

<TD class="ms-disc-bordered-noleft">Value 3</TD>

<TD class="ms-disc-bordered-noleft">
<A HREF="/Threaded.aspx?RootFolder=%2fLists&amp;FolderCTID=0x01200">Value 4</A>
</TD></TR>

........and so on 

</Table>
```

i am trying to pick "Value 4" the last having string "FolderCTID" in href and insertBefore "Value 1" with div class that starts with "ExternalClass".

**I want to insertBefore the each element in the row to the corresponding element in the same row**

I am using following code:

```
$('a[href*="FolderCTID"]').insertBefore($('div[class^="ExternalClass"]'));
```

But it is inserting all the elements for every row....i think i should make something to specify the entities and loop around each end of the entity...

Please help me on this

Comment: It would help a lot if you used http://jsfiddle.net/ to describe your problem. Enter your html and javascript and click Save, then add the link to your question.

Comment: @Jimmy **Updated HTML and used JQuery**

Answer (score 1):

you have to look for the ExternalClass only inside the current tr so you could do something like this as a startingpoint:

```
$.each($('a[href*="FolderCTID"]'), function() {
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).parents('tr').find('div[class^="ExternalClass"]'));
});
```

Comment: as u suggested ' $('a[href*="FolderCTID"]').each(function(){
$(this).insertBefore($(this).parents('tr').find('div[class^="ExternalClass"]'));
  } ); '  but no luck ..**returning all the elements collectively for each element**