# JQuery Truncate Text and insert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using some Jquery to insert a element before another element as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href*="FolderCTID"]').each(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('div[class^="ExternalClass"]').before(this);
    });
});
```

I am able successfully insert before the element

But, **.find('div[class^="ExternalClass"]')** in the script above is the element i want to truncate before inserting on runtime.

Please help me, how i can truncate the text before i actually insert

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of truncation are you trying to perform?  To a specific length?  At a specific place?

Comment: @justkt im trying to truncate specific length of characters

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var truncateLength = 10;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href*="FolderCTID"]').each(function(){
        var div = $(this).closest('tr').find('div[class^="ExternalClass"]');
        var text = div.text();
        div.text(text.subString(0, text.length > truncateLength  ? truncateLength  : text.length));
        div.insertBefore(this); // insertBefore rather than before
    }); 
 });
```

Comment: Sorry, the script returns nothing

Comment: @Jam - Updated to use insertBefore rather than before. Can you test it now?

Answer (score 0):

```
var someelement = $(this).closest('tr').find('div[class^="ExternalClass"]');
someelement.html(function(i,h){ return h.substring(0,10); });
someelement.before(this);
```

Comment: Sorry, the script returns nothing

Comment: how about this? http://jsfiddle.net/GvKLh/ I used the script from my answer in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152145/jquery-insertafter-dom-elements/5152414#5152414